# Singularity under a intergral

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Currently I am working on the book Partial Differential Equation by Lawrence C. Evans. I have problem to understand a certain part of the proof of Theorem 1 in Section 2.2., where they try to solve the poisson equation for $f\in C_c^2(\Bbb R^n)$

Given$$I_\epsilon=\int_{B(0,\epsilon)}\Phi(y)\Delta_xf(x-y)dy$$ where $B(0,\epsilon)$ is an open ball and $f$ a function, which is twice continuously differentiable, with compact support. i.e. an element of the space $C^2_c(\Bbb R^n)$. The $\Phi(y)$ is defined as
 $$\Phi(y) =
\begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{2\pi}log|x|  & \text{if n=2} \\
\frac{1}{n(n-2)\alpha(n)}\frac{1}{|x|^{n-2}} & \text{if n$\geq$3}
\end{cases}$$.

Now there are few inequalities which I dont understand, they claim$$|I_\epsilon|\leq C||D^2f||_{L^\infty}\int_{B(0,\epsilon)}|\Phi(y)|dy
\leq\begin{cases}C\epsilon^2|log(\epsilon)|  & \text{if n=2} \\ C\epsilon^2 & \text{if n$\geq$3}\end{cases}$$.
The norm $||\cdot||_{L^{\infty}}$ denotes the essential supremum and $D$ is the differential operator I assume.

Question:

1. The first inequality is more or less clear as they took the supremum before the integral. However, where does the constant C arise from?
2. I am total lost with the second inequality. I cannot see why this should hold as $\Phi(y)$ has a singularity at 0 and hence, one cannot find an upper bound. How can this inequality hold?

Comment: If the singularity is sufficiently small, it is integrable. For instance, $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} dx$ is well defined. So is the integral of $log(x)$

Comment: @Joel Yes you are right. However I am interested in how they can give an upper bound of the integral. Where is the inequality coming from.

Comment: I think these estimates come from using polar coordinates. In two dimensions you just get $r dr d\theta$ from the Jacobian. Generally it will give you $r^{n-1}$ from the Jacobian in higher dimensions. Check the appendix in Evans. I think he reviews it in there.